# Not able to get ZIP file in artfiacts created by MSBuild arguments in Jenkins build

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, msbuild

[image]

I am trying to build .NET project on Jenkins with MsBuild plugin. I am passing few required arguments to make a ZIP package to deploy to AWS Elastic beanstalk. I have used this MsBuild arguments before in TFS. It worked as expected. When I tried in Jenkins. I am not getting any zip file in build output (artifacts).
These are the arguments, I am passing in Jenkins job:

```
/p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /P:PackageTempRootDir=\Release 
/p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site";DefaultPackageFileName=TDApi_Test.zip 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true"
```

I have also tried few other arguments, like `/t:rebuild /p:PackageLocation="${WORKSPACE}\Release"`. It didn't work as well.

My build is completing successful. Problem is, it's not getting artifact as accepted.

Comment: Which version of msbuild/VS do you use? If you only installed the 2017 build tools, you might be running into https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901

Comment: Installed version:::C:\Administrator>msbuild -version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.6.1590.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: That's the .net framework included msbuild, you'll want the One shipping with VS (14 for vs 2015, 15 for VS 2017)

Comment: I don't have full VS installed. I have only vs agent installed on Jenkins server and agents. I read that we don't need to install full VS to use MSBuild with Jenkins. Also, /p:OutDir="${WORKSPACE}/TDapi" this MSBuild argument is working. I am getting _PublishedWebsite gettting created by OutDir argument. But arguments which is used to zip it. it's not working. as i mentioned in my question "DefaultPackageFileName" argument is not working.

Comment: It looks like, it's not an issue with jenkins. It's an issue with MSBuild version or due to not having VS installed. I tried to build project locally with msbuild arguments. It's giving me same output. It's ignoring arguments. Does anyone know why should MSBuild ignores arguments?

Comment: msbuild ignores all arguments that it doesn't know. it's up to the targets that are installed in the msbuild installation to make us of the arguments. Is VS installed on the agent? or at least build tools (in vs2017 build tools with web workload)

Comment: when you run msbuild locally, always use the `Developer Command Prompt`

Comment: I got it. I will need to install full VS on jenkins agent. I can run the same arguments in other server where i have installed full VS 2015.

Comment: I installed full VS 2015 on jenkins agent. When i try to run locally msbuild with developer tool cmd or windows cmd. it's working fine. but jenkins is still not working properly. I have removed the manually added path for msbuild it was targeted to .NET Framework. Right now, in Environment variable MSBuild path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin". Any idea why jenkins is not recognizing right MSBuild version?

Answer (score 0):

The VS 2017 build tools did not include web publishing targets by default, so a full VS installation is needed.

According to https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901 this problem has been fixed in VS 2017 Build Tools >= 15.3 (26430.04).

Comment: I installed full VS 2015 on jenkins agent. When i try to run locally msbuild with developer tool cmd or windows cmd. it's working fine. but jenkins is still not working properly. I have removed the manually added path for msbuild it was targeted to .NET Framework. Right now, in Environment variable MSBuild path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin". Any idea why jenkins is not recognizing right MSBuild version